# How to set values of alfresco-global.properties programmatically

Tags: alfresco, cmis, opencmis

I was working in a client application with alfresco and in need to capture the changes in docs from user's alfresco account. From further reading I came to know that I need to set some properties in ***alfresco-global.properties*** file to enable change log audit. So is there anyway I can do this using an API without requesting user to do this ? Please help

Comment: Edit @alfresco-global.properties@, configure audit, restart Alfresco.

Comment: @LutzHorn :  I know that. But I wanted to know whether I can do the same programmatically.

Comment: The Alfresco EE stores changes you make in the EE Admin Console in the internal attribute store. Note that these changes are *not* persisted in the @alfresco-global.properties@. If you use the Alfresco CE, you must restart the system.

Comment: Do you have a Community or Enterprise ? Which version ? It might be an important information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Community there is no direct way to do this other than using addon's or writing your own custom code.

There are some ways you can use when using the JavaScript Api of Alfresco.

There is an Open Source module [here](https://github.com/loftuxab/alfresco-jmx) using JMX and a paid one [here](http://www.contezza.nl/store/p26/Contezza_Alfresco_Admin_Console.html) using a custom Share page.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure something like that is possible, other then using JMX. I'd be happy is someone would prove me wrong, though.

http://docs.alfresco.com/5.1/concepts/jmx-intro-config.html

Comment: You know this is Enterprise only for Community you'll need an addon or fix something yourself